# How to create an event series with a start date and an end date

Tags: google-calendar-api

First of all, sorry if my English isn't good as I'm a french guy.

I have a problem with a google script I took on the internet that automatically inputs holliday in my calendar.

Let me explain in detail: I use a google form to get all the data I need to input my calendar, such as the name of the employee, the start date of his holliday, the end date, and other information like mail and stuff. The start date and end date are with hours to indicate at which hour start and finish the holliday.

Here's my problem, I use CreateEventSeries but when I use this, it creates a "bar" until the end date but I would like to have an event day by day, until the end date, that finish at 18pm.

Here's the code i use :

```
  else if (approval == Approval.Approved && reason == Reason.Vacation) {
    CalendarApp.getCalendarById(email)
      .createEventSeries(
         'CP',
         startDate,
         endDate,
        CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addWeeklyRule()
        .onlyOnWeekdays([CalendarApp.Weekday.MONDAY, CalendarApp.Weekday.TUESDAY, CalendarApp.Weekday.WEDNESDAY, CalendarApp.Weekday.THURSDAY, CalendarApp.Weekday.FRIDAY])
        .until(endDate),

    
            {
              description: message,
              sendInvites: true,
            }
            );

    // Send a confirmation email.
    let subject = 'Congés acceptés';
    MailApp.sendEmail(additionalEmail, subject, message, );

    row[Header.NotifiedStatus] = NotifiedStatus.Notified;

    Logger.log(`Approved, calendar event created, row=${JSON.stringify(row)}`);
      
  }
```

I don't know if I made myself clear.

I don't want an all-day event cause it's not visible enough on the calendar.

In short, I would like to create an event series day by day from 8 am until 18pm with a start date and an end date.

Does someone have a solution or a lead?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue:

When creating an event series via [createEventSeries(title, startTime, endTime, recurrence, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createEventSeries(String,Date,Date,EventRecurrence,Object)), the parameters `startTime` and `endTime` refer to the start and end time of the **first event in the series**, not of the series as a whole:

> **startTime**: the date and time when the first event in the series starts
>
> **endTime**:  the date and time when the first event in the series ends

This `endTime` is completely different from what you want to set at [until(endDate)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/recurrence-rule#until(Date)), which refers to when the series of events will finish.

#### Code snippet:

For example, if you want to have an event every day that lasts from 8 AM to 6 PM, from, let's say, 1 to 15 May, you would do this:

```
const startTime = new Date('May 1, 2021 08:00:00 GMT+01:00');
const endTime = new Date('May 1, 2021 18:00:00 GMT+01:00');
const endDate = new Date('May 15, 2021 18:00:00 GMT+01:00');
const recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addWeeklyRule()
    .onlyOnWeekdays([
      CalendarApp.Weekday.MONDAY, 
      CalendarApp.Weekday.TUESDAY, 
      CalendarApp.Weekday.WEDNESDAY, 
      CalendarApp.Weekday.THURSDAY, 
      CalendarApp.Weekday.FRIDAY
    ])
    .until(endDate)
CalendarApp.getCalendarById(email).createEventSeries('CP',startTime,endTime,recurrence);
```

#### Update:

Assuming you have installed an [onFormSubmit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder#onFormSubmit()) trigger, your function could be something like this:

```
function createEventSeriesOnSubmit(e) {
  const formResponse = e.response;
  let itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
  const itemNames = ["startDate", "endDate", "startHour", "endHour"];
  const responses = itemNames.map(itemName => getResponseForItem(itemResponses, itemName));
  const [startDay, endDay, startHour, endHour] = responses;
  const startTime = new Date(`${startDay} ${startHour}`);
  const endTime = new Date(`${startDay} ${endHour}`);
  const endDate = new Date(`${endDay} ${endHour}`);
  const recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addWeeklyRule()
      .onlyOnWeekdays([
        CalendarApp.Weekday.MONDAY, 
        CalendarApp.Weekday.TUESDAY, 
        CalendarApp.Weekday.WEDNESDAY, 
        CalendarApp.Weekday.THURSDAY, 
        CalendarApp.Weekday.FRIDAY
      ])
      .until(endDate)
  CalendarApp.getCalendarById(email).createEventSeries('CP',startTime,endTime,recurrence);
}
```

Where `"startDate", "endDate", "startHour", "endHour"` are the names of the corresponding items in your Form. For example:

[image]

As you can see in the code sample, you can build the corresponding date to use in calendar by interpolating the date response and the time response, like this:

```
const startTime = new Date(`${startDay} ${startHour}`);
```

The resulting calendar has the series of events corresponding to the start hour, end hour, start date and end date that have been specified:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I tried something yesterday before reading your answer.
I separated the hours and the date in my google sheet and i have created two more constant for it. 
My idea was to do something like this when using .createEventSeries :
.createEventSeries('CP', startdate&&starthour, startdate&endhour,recurrence).

The endhour is always 18:00:00 and the starthour is always 08:00:00 so I was thinking that could work the way I want in creating an eventseries and it did for like a couple of hours, but I guess I did something cause it's not working anymore and I don't know why

Comment: @lamblichus I tried your code but it didn't solve my problem. Let me clarify, Your code works only for 1 to 15 may as you said, but in my case, my colleagues fill up a google form for their time off so the start day will change accordingly and the same goes for the end date. I have 4 constants called, startday, starthour, endday and endhour, so I tried remplacing them in the new date() but that doesn't work either. There is probably something i'm missing.

Comment: @KevinBerard That means you will need an [onFormSubmit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder#onFormSubmit()) trigger, which could then use the response information to set up the dates. Please note, though, that this information is not part of your question, and that the issue you mentioned in your question was indeed solved, in which case I'd suggest creating a new question. In any case, if you clarify what the 4 constants are (are they strings? What format? Or dates?), I would like to update my answer to adapt it to your exact situation.

Comment: @lamblichus Yeah through your responses I figured I didn't make myself clear enough and your first response was indeed what I asked for at first. That's totaly my bad on this one.
For my constants, the start and endday are DateItem. Start and endhour are TimeItem. I think what I'm missing is linked with my Time constants. To be honest i don't know for sure because my constants are declared like this : const header { StartDate: 'Start Date', StartHour: 'Start Hour' ... } and i have something like this below : form.addDateItem().settitle(Header.StartDate) etc ...

Comment: @KevinBerard I updated my answer in order to indicate how you could retrieve the dates specified in the form and use those to create the event series. Please note that this is not part of your original question and also this would make this question too broad, so I'd consider posting a new question if you have further doubts. I hope this is helpful.

Comment: @lamblichus thank you very much for taking your time to answer to my lack of knowledge in this field even if my questions were not what I originally asked.  Your update is exactly what I'm dealing with, I tried your code and in the log it work but it doesn't display my time off on my calendar, it only appear when I don't use the starthour or endhour, but I will be able to search on my side. Thank you again for your time